# Update one dataset with another without using PROC SQL

Tags: sas

I have the below two datasets

Dataset A

```
id age  mark
1  .    .
2  .    .
1  .    .
```

Dataset B

```
id age mark
2  20  200
1  10  100
```

I need the below dataset as output

Output Dataset

```
id age mark
1  10  100
2  20  200
1  10  100
```

How to carry out this without using **PROC SQL** i.e. using **DATA STEP**?

Comment: If you wanted to preserve the order of data set A, you could use the HASH OBJECT and treat data set B as a lookup table

Comment: Why not just use proc sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  The easiest is to sort the two data sets and then use `MERGE`.  For example:

```
proc sort data=A;
   by id;
run;
proc sort data=B;
   by id;
run;

data WANT;
  merge A(drop=age mark) B;
     by ID;
run;
```

The trick is to **drop** the variables you are adding from the first data set `A`; the new variables will come from the second data set `B`.

Of course, this solution does not preserve the original order of the observations in your data set **AND** only works because your second data set contains unique values of `id`.

Comment: Do you maybe know if there is a way to reference the columns of datasets A and B in the data step? And do something like `coalesce(a.age, b.age)`, as you would in `proc sql`?

Comment: Data set "columns" are referred to as "variables" in SAS.  And you just refer to them by name.  Also, the SAS data step language does include the `COALESCE` function, but in the data step, you cannot refer to the same variable name in two different data sets.  Much can be learned in the online documentation. Start with the **System Concepts** chapter here:  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/65287/HTML/default/viewer.htm#titlepage.htm

Comment: Good solution but you may have oversimplified it (depending on the OP's exact needs).  If the rows to update are a subset of the existing dataset then you will unintentionally lose data because you are dropping the columns and those values don't exist in the subset.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me, even if you have data you would like to preserve in that column. Just for completeness sake I added an SQL variant too.

```
data a;
input id a;
datalines;
1 10
2 20
;

data b;
input id a;
datalines;
1 .
1 5
1 .
2 .
3 4
;

data c (drop=b);
merge a (rename = (a=b) in=ina) b (in = inb);
by id;
if b ne . then a = b;
run;

proc sql;
create table d as
select a.id, a.a from a right  join b on a.id=b.id where a.id is not null
union all
select b.id, b.a from a right join b on a.id = b.id where a.id is null
;
quit;
```